# Holomorphic in the half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that the map $M(z) : (z + 1)/(z − 1)$ is holomorphic in the half-plane given by $H = \left\{z ∈ C : Re z < 0\right\}$ and that $M(H) \subset D_1(0)$.

I am unsure how to prove that it is holomorphic just for Re $z < 0$? and where I then go from here.
Any help would be much appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Showing that $M$ is holomorphic is not a big deal, since sums and quotients of differentiable things are differentiable.

The statement that $M$ maps $H$ into $D_1(0)$ is equivalent to saying that $|z+1| < |z-1|$ for all $z \in H$, or in other words that $z$ is closer to $-1$ than it is to $1$.

Comment: I know that I can state these things and say that the function is holomorphic for all $\mathbb{C}\setminus {z=1}$ but I am wondering speifically how to show this for Re $z <0$? Do i need to consider different values for $z$ to do this?

Comment: If it's holomorphic on $\mathbb C - \{1\}$, it's also holomorphic on any smaller open set, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the problem to show the function is holomorphic. Any rational function is holomorphic in a domain where the denominator is not zero.

If you know about Mobius transformations then you can use their properties to show that $M(H)\subset D_1(0)$. But here it is easy even without Mobius transformations, just show that $\frac{|z+1|^2}{|z-1|^2}<1$ for all $z$ such that $Re(z)<0$. Use the fact that $|w|^2=w\bar{w}$.

Comment: Thank you @Mark